# Timer job to delete History from SharePoint_Config.dbo.TimerJobHistory is not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010

The Database `SharePoint_Config` is getting bigger and bigger and now it is 16 GB. I have run this command `SPTimerJob job-delete-job-history` in Power Shell and it gave me this output:

```
Name                 Schedule             Last Run
----                 --------             --------
job-delete-job-hi... weekly at sun 05:... 20.11.2011 05:00:00
```

I want to run this job now, and I tried this command but nothing happens. No output, no error.

```
Get-SPTimerJob job-delete-job-history | Start-SPTimerJob
```

I need help to clear the data from the table `SharePoint_Config.dbo.TimerJobHistory`

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your SP Config DB [TimerJobHistory] table is bloated because the CA [Delete Job History] Timer Job has not been executed on a weekly basis; you can check the last time it ran in CA, Job Defintions, [Delete Job History]. If the [Delete Job History] Timer Job has not been executed in more than a week, then you need to consider executing the Timer Job manually.

Care needs to be taken if the [Delete Job History] Timer Job has not been run for some time because executing the job will attempt to purge old data from the [TimerJobHistory] table and this will cause your SP Config DB TLog file to grow as the transactions are being purged.

Here's an approach that I have used to gradually purge old data from the [TimerJobHistory] table whilst also monitoring and shrinking the SP Config DB TLog file between executions of the [Delete Job History] Timer Job.

```
# Execute [Delete Job History] Timer Job
# Job Title: Delete Job History
# Job Description: Deletes old entries from the timer job history.
# Recurring Schedule: Weekly, Sunday @ 05:00

$job = Get-SPTimerJob | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "job-delete-job-history"}
# If this Timer Job has not been executed on a regular basis (weekly), then the 
# dbo.TimerJobHistory table will have a larger then normal amount of stored rows 
# which need to be purged. In which case, execution of this Timer Job will cause 
# the SP Config DB Transaction Log file to grow as this TimerJob is active.
# In this case, set the DaysToKeepHistory Property to a high value and execute 
# the Timer Job repeatedly gradually decreasing the DaysToKeepHistory Property 
# value until you reach the 7 days default value.
#$job.DaysToKeepHistory = 365 # The default value is 7
#$job.Update()
$job.RunNow()
```